# Error creating SVN Repository in Linux

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I´m creating a svn repository in my Linux server and this are the commands I´m using:

1. I´m in /home/myuser folder
2. I create a folder: **mkdir repository_folder**
3. Then I go to that folder: **cd repository_folder**
4. Then I create the repository: **svnadmin create test**
5. From this point I have some questions, because I don´t see the trunk,tags and branches folders and the folder structure is:

   - conf
   - db
   - format
   - hooks
   - locks
   - README.txt
6. If I try inside the repository folder: **svn mkdir trunk** , it returns me an error: "svn: '.' is not a working copy"
7. If I want to import a project from /home/myuser/myproject to /home/myuser/repository_folder/test/trunk , the command should be: **svn import /home/myuser/myproject file:///home/myuser/repository_folder/test/trunk -m "some message"** ??

What am I doing wrong when creating the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are confusing Subversion  [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) with a [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository). It is expected to see those conf, db, format, hooks etc directories and files on file system.

If you want to create /trunk /branches and /tags directories in the repository, use the command `svn mkdir file:///home/myuser/repository_folder/test/trunk file:///home/myuser/repository_folder/test/branches file:///home/myuser/repository_folder/test/tags -m "Initial repository structure"`. BTW, make sure that the path to the repository is valid.

Otherwise, you can `svn checkout` the working copy of the repository using `svn checkout file:///home/myuser/repository_folder/test/`. Then create the necessary structure, `svn add` the new directories and `svn commit` them to the repository.

Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

Comment: Thanks,it works. And I´m with the book open since some days ago,and sometimes the book isn´t too clear.